# Laravel 5 Session Doesn't Work on Redirect

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-session

I am having trouble with developing a Laravel application. When I set a session from a function and loaded the view the session will show:

```
Session::flash("test","ABC");

return view('layout.customer');
```

But when I set a session and redirect it to a URL in that page, the session will not work. I am currently using following code:

```
Session::flash("test","ABC");

return redirect()->route('customer.details');
```

Answer (score 2):

Variables that are flashed only last one request.

When you send a redirect, the redirect itself is the first request sent to the visitor. On this request the existing flash session is cleared. 
Now a second requests starts for the page that is being redirected to and the session flashes no longer exist.

---

**Update:**

You can use the `with` function to add flashed data to a redirect.

```
return redirect()->route('customer.details')->with("test","ABC");
```

More info: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: I need to take the success message after a form submission what is the best approach to do it

Comment: I tried with that one as well it also becomes empty when i try to print on the view

Comment: Can you try to use `session('test')` instead of `session()->get('test')`? See https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/session#retrieving-data

Answer (score 0):

You can use `return redirect()->route('customer.details')->with("test","ABC");`to flash the data when redirecting. Here's the documentation for this: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data

Comment: I tried with that one also it also not works do I need to set any libraries for redirecting?

Comment: Can you show the code you use to display the data on the page?

Comment: [code]@if (session()->has('test'))
                    <div class="alert alert-info">{{ (session()->get('test')) }}</div>
 @endif[code]

Comment: Write `{{ session()->get('test') }}` instead.

Answer (score -1):

In customer.details controller add line use Session; at top of the page.

Comment: its on the same controller when i used to redirect. and Session is already loaded.

Comment: then try this code in your view blade:

@if(Session::has('test'))
<p class="alert {{ Session::get('test') }}">{{ Session::get('test') }}</p>
@endif